# How to place an item under another item using flxbox?

Tags: html, css

I have a JS fiddle here and it's pretty simple what I want to happen but difficult for me to execute it. In the fiddle, you notice there is a red box. I want that red box to be displayed under the text "Join Balance...". I am not sure how to do this.

Can somebody help me?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2h390wc/

HTML and CSS:

```css
/* newsletter section */

#custom_html-5 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  padding-left: 70px !important;
  padding-right: 20px !important;
}

.newsletter_inner_section {
  display: flex;
}

.newsletter_gif {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

.newsletter_left,
.newsletter_center,
.newsletter_right {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.newsletter_left {
  width: auto;
}

.newsletter_center {
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.newsletter_right {
  background: red;
  width: 40%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.newsletter_text_section {
  color: black !important;
  font-size: 24px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.eVEmvD.eVEmvD.eVEmvD.eVEmvD.eVEmvD.eVEmvD {
  width: fit-content !important;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.fGCWnQ.fGCWnQ {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.kvTDNe.kvTDNe {
  display: unset;
}


/* Media Newsletter section only */

@media (max-width:1144px) {
  #custom_html-5 {
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
  }
  .newsletter_inner_section {
    width: 100% !important;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
  }
  .newsletter_center,
  .newsltter_right {
    flex-direction: column !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- newsletter section -->

<div class="newsletter_section">
  <div class="newsletter_inner_section">
    <div class="newsletter_left">
      <img src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/wp-content/themes/balancecoffeechild/img/newsletternnobkg2.gif" alt="Balance Newsletter" style="padding-right:30px;" class="newsletter_gif">
    </div>
    <div class="newsletter_center">
      <p class="newsletter_text_section">Join Balance and get 20% off your first order</p>
    </div>
    <div class="newsletter_right">
      <div class="newsletter_input_section">
        <div class="klaviyo-form-Rrsqsh"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text and the red box on the right to form a column, then they both need to be in a flexbox with `flex-direction: column;`.

I created a sample from scratch because there is a lot of superfluous stuff in your JSFiddle.

```css
.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 40px;
}

.left {
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top-right {
  background-color: green;
}

.bottom-right {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='group'>
  <div class='left content-box'>
    Content
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <div class='top-right content-box'>
      Content
    </div>
    <div class='bottom-right content-box'>
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```